# Couldn't find path for a component in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm currently working on an angular web app and it's my first time ever using Angular.
I started from an existing template with already some components, but i wanted to create a custom new one and I'm having some problems.
I created a new folder inside the app/components folder with the html, scss and ts files, and also imported the file inside the app.module.ts.
The fact is: it won't work, because it doesn't find the path.

I think that maybe I need to add some other code lines in some other file to tell them "hey, it's linked and it does exist" or something like that.

Comment: Did you add the new component to the routing module file?

Comment: Yup! It gives me an error as if the file in the path doesn't exist.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's your first time using angular I would suggest you use a command line to generate it.

- open the folder where you want to create the component
- type command : ng g c nameOfTheComponent
- go to the routing module and add the route

route:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: 'my-component',
            component: nameOfTheComponent
        }
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
        imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
    })
```

Comment: I found the part of the code where the template creator created all the other components, and it had the same syntax as your part of code. I tried adding the new line with my new component and it turned light blue instead of green (the color of the other components) and it still gives me errors. Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: can you screenshot the errors that u have in the console?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply, but I work on that bug during my work shift. Anyway, I found out the error source, I feel extremely stupid for that but it's ok since I knew nothing about Angular.

My component was well-created, but it had some pieces of code from Angular material and I didn't know it was something I had to install from my terminal.

Thanks a lot for trying to help me, though!